# Can't choose MS Acess as an option for a ODBC User DSN: why?

Tags: windows-7, odbc, dsn

I try to setup an User DSN using an MS Access driver, but although visible as an option in the User DSN tab I only can choose for SQL Server in the second dialog. Why?

I am using Windows 7 and Access 2007.

[image]

Comment: It means the drivers are not really installed / working for those three listed User Data Sources. They are default definitions and if you try and configure any of them (double click) you will get an error. It is a 32bit/64bit thing as mentioned in one of the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it myself: [Unable to create DSN for Microsoft Office System Driver on 64-bit versions of Windows](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2721825).

So you have to use `%windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`

Comment: correct, the old Jet Engine is 32Bit only. Starting with Office 2010 and the ACE you have a 64bit version.